# How do I tell jQuery that an AJAX request was successful?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form with AJAX through jQuery:

```
$('.submit input').click(function() {return false;});

$("#addcourseform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formcont = $(this).serialize();
    $.post({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>handover/courseadd",
        data: formcont,
        success: function(returned) {
            alert("It worked: "+returned);
        }
    });
});
```

This above code is wrapped in ready(), returns no errors in the console, and all that good stuff. However, it seems to append [object Object] to the end of the POST url. Since I use CodeIgniter, that throws a 400 Bad Request because it includes disallowed characters in the URL.

How do I get jQuery from adding that?

EDIT POST-FIX:

For those future people reading this and thinking I'm an idiot, I did in fact use the post() syntax wrong.

Comment: `return false;` from the submit method to prevent actual submission.  You would probably be better handling the `.click()` method, again returning `false`.

Comment: The best way to diagnose AJAX is within the developer console of your browser, i.e. Firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**$.post** is not the same as **$.ajax** so you have to provide the parameters differently.

Try this:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>handover/courseadd", 
        $(this).serialize(), 
        function(returned){     
            alert("It worked: " + returned);
        });
```

Or just replace **post** with **ajax** in your current code.

Comment: Yea just noticed that as well. Changing the $.post to $.ajax should fix his problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: This is actually the oldest error one can make in jQuery - you probably forgot to wrap the whole thing in a `ready()` handler. :)

[JSFiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/khd6b/4/)

Comment: And another one: `var formcont = $(this).serialize());` (double closing brace).

Comment: Actually, it is wrapped in ready(), I just chunked out the bit of code I needed to show you guys.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be something else. I updated the main post :(

Answer (score 2):

You have another syntax error:

```
var formcont = $(this).serialize());
```

Remove the last `)`:

```
var formcont = $(this).serialize();
```

Have a look at your console in your browser, it should log these kinds of problems for you to easily spot.

Comment: +1. To be fair, Chrome's console forgets all previous error messages when the page is switched - I had to switch to Firefox to see this

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. But at least we got somewhere :) I've been coding for 18 hours straight, sorry.

Comment: Fixed. Not working. And also, the Developer Console in Chrome doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @Pekka It at least throws me the error on DOM load already with Chrome. I've personally come to like Chrome's console for javascript work more than Firebug :) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/5uYre/

Comment: @Brandon can you add a `complete` event and throw an alert in there, to see if that gets called?

Comment: I can, but I have more information that may help. Updated main post.